# Guitar sound like in a Seether's song

Tags: guitar, sound

I adore the sound of guitar in Seether's song "Fade out",
Can anyone help me to reach such sound by setting my guitar processor in a certain way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular part of the song that has a particular guitar sound you like? It seems to be a pretty normal slightly overdriven, warm, distorted guitar.

I can recreate it pretty well with a Marshall amp simulator with the gain about 5, bass 7, mid 5, treble 7 fed with a mild distortion.

Generally I have the mids cut and a bit more distortion, so tweaking the mid up a little and backing off the distortion just gives a more mellow, rounded sound.